# Logic: Predicate P(x,y) with only one defined parameter?

Tags: predicate-logic

I have a question about well-formed/well-defined predicates. Our class was presented with the following exercise:

> > Let ${S}$ denote the set of all students in your class, ${C}$ denotes the set of all  countries, and $T(x, y)$ denotes that $x$ travels to country $y$.
> >
> > Express the following by a simple English sentence. Avoid symbols and predicates in  English sentences.
> >
> > $\neg T(Bob, y)$"

It seems to me that it is not appropriate to define only one of the variables in the predicate; it says "Bob does not travel to country $y$," but $y$ was never quantified or put in a domain (it doesn't say $y \in {C}$ -- so can we still assume $y$ is a country?),  but our professor told us it was a 'valid open statement' the way it was written, and we could assume $y$ was a country.

I just wanted to know if it is in fact proper to symbolize things this way. I have looked at the other posts but am still not certain. There are similar examples ($"L(x,y)"$ standing for "$x$ likes $y$") that make me wonder if it is okay to write things this way.  Clarification is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: To be very careful, one could add something like this: For $(x,y)\in S\times C$, $T(x,y)$ denotes that...  Apparently your professor is not requiring that much formality in this one (which really is pretty clear from context).  I note that in the question, it doesn't explicitly say that Bob is a student.

Comment: Thank you- you are right that the prof is not being very formal. Our task was to evaluate the sentence as is, and I said I thought that technically there was insufficient information to do so, but apparently that was not the right answer.